# How can i pass an imagae path from database to css property

Tags: css, node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have URLs in **MongoDB** i want to pass these URLs from my Database to `background-image` in css, how can i do that in NODE JS & MONGO DB

I am using **HBS, Node js, Express js, and mongoDB**

Comment: perhaps this answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127076/dynamically-set-a-css-property-based-on-a-template-value

Comment: A straightforward way is to directly insert the full URL into a handlebars template: `<div style="background-image: url({{ the_url }})">...</div>`